# On a problem of convergence of measure for Levy measures

Tags: probability-theory

I have a question that pertains to the Levy representation of infinitely divisible distributions. However, the technical item that is relevant to me right now is one that relates to weak or vague convergence.

More specifically, assume that we are given a sequence of Levy measures $\{\nu_n: n \in N\}, $  i.e., each $\nu_n $ is such that $\nu_n(\{0\}) = 0 $ and $\int_{R\setminus \{0\}} (1\wedge x^2)\, \nu_n(dx) < \infty $ for each $n \in N. $

Assume that $\nu_n \to $ weakly as $n \to \infty. $ It is easy to see that in this case $\nu(\{0\}) = 0. $ But how can one prove (or disprove, but I think that the claim is correct) that we have also
$$ \int_{R\setminus \{0\}} (1\wedge x^2)\, \nu(dx) < \infty ? $$

Clearly $1\wedge x^2 $ is continuous and bounded on $R\setminus \{0\} $ which means that
$$ \int_{R\setminus \{0\}} (1\wedge x^2)\, \nu_n (dx) \to \int_{R\setminus \{0\}} (1\wedge x^2)\, \nu(dx) $$ 
as $n \to \infty, $ and it is relatively easy to prove that $\nu_n $ is $\sigma$-finite, 
but how about proving that the last integral is finite? 
Thank you in advance for any help.

Maurice

NOTE. By $(1\wedge x^2) $  it is meant $\min\{1, x^2\}. $

Comment: Which one is the "last" integral? If $\int (1 \wedge x^2) \nu_n(dx)$ is finite, then $\int (1 \wedge x^2) \nu(dx)$ is finite since it is a limit of a (bounded) sequence.

Comment: Thank you, saz, but is it really bounded? I mean all I know is that $\int (1 \wedge x^2)\, \nu_n(dx) < \infty $ and not that it is less than some $K< \infty $ for each value of $n. $ Am I missing something?

Comment: Well, but that's what weak convergence is about, isn't it? If $\nu_n$ converges weakly to $\nu$, then we have $$\int f(x) \nu_n(dx) \to \int f(x) \nu(dx); $$ this means in particular (...at least in the definitions I know...) that the right-hand side is finite. However, the notion of weak convergence is usually defined for finite measures - so do you mean vague convergence (and not weak convergence)?

Comment: For this particular type it is akin to vague convergence as the measures are not necessarily probability measures.

Comment: But it might be probability measures. For example the sequence $\nu_n(dx) := \delta_n(dx)$ defines a sequence of Lévy measures which converges vaguely but not weakly. However, perhaps someone else is capable to answer your question.

Comment: Yes, saz, in one instance I found an academic claiming that since $\int f d\nu_n \to \int f d\nu $ for every continuous and bounded $f $ then $\nu(R) < \infty. $ which I find suspicious. In fact, nowhere either Kallenberg in his Foundations of Modern Probability or Sato in its Levy Processes and Infinite divisible distributions use such a trivial argument. And I became suspicious.